# Implementing operator++ for an open hash table

Tags: c++, iterator, hashtable

I have the following layout for creating an open hash table iterator:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
class HT{
private:
    struct info{
        int key;
        int di;
    };
    vector< list<info> > data;
public:
    class iterator{
    private:
        list<info>::iterator bucket_it;
        vector< list<info> >::iterator it;
    };
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
}
```

Can someone show me how operator++ should be implemented? I'm thinking about this solution:

```
   iterator& operator++(){
    ++bucket_it;
    if(bucket_it == it->end()){
        ++it;
        if(it != end()){ //???
          bucket_it = it->begin();
        }else{
          bucket_it = //???
        }
    }
   }
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to know the end iterator of vector without knowing the container. Also, I can't figure out what value should bucket_it be set to in this case.

Comment: I strongly suggest replacing `list` with `vector` in your code. It’s almost guaranteed to improve performance characteristics. Of course that’s unrelated to your actual question.

Comment: You need to store a reference to the data vector inside the iterator.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ??? `operator++(int)` returns (a copy of) the value before modification. You are right about the fact that you don't usually return a reference, though. But: the example is `operator++()` (note the missing dummy int).

Comment: When `it == data.end()`, you are beyond the last bucket, you are done. No need to even touch `bucket_it` at all. Just remember to overload `operator==()` and `operator!=()` accordingly (i.e. don't ever touch `bucket_it` when `it == data.end()`).

Comment: @dhke Oops, yes, I've been overlooking that.

Comment: You need your iterator to have a way to know `HT::data.end()` - you can either store a snapshot of the value when you create the iterator, or a reference or pointer to `data` (or even the `HT` object) so you can get a more dynamic `end()` value to compare to).  Your decision will impact the `HT::iterator` invalidation characteristics, and performance to a small degree.